# I cannot run or install my Linux mint OS in HP laptop

Tags: ubuntu, bios, grub, linux-mint, reboot

I wanted to dual boot with windows 10. I have already install linux mint with usb-flash but I got stuck in the Grub and whenever I click linux mint os the black screen just appear forever without doing nothing.I have disabled secure boot and legacy boot also. This is the video that I uploaded just to make my problem clear https://youtu.be/SZJkw-IFCqE Please watch it and notify me on how to solve it. Thank You

Comment: You indicated you disabled Secure Boot and Legacy Boot does that mean you installed Linux with UEFI mode enabled? YouTube is blocked in my region so you will have to edit your question to provide information

Comment: Is Windows 10 working fine? When you installed Windows 10 earlier (whenever it was) do you know if it was in Legacy MBR mode or UEFI Mode? You can check it anyways by running msinfo32.exe as such. What if on the boot menu you go into Advanced Options? Does it show the next set of options, if so what if you try Linux Generic? Does it boot?

Comment: yes my windows 10 is working fine. I have already installed linuxmint when I open with compatibility mode after installing, i eject my flash drive and restart it. if I choose windows 10 it works just fine but if I choose linux mint the black screen just appear forevre.

Comment: As I mentioned in my earlier comment, did you try Advanced Options from the same menu?

Comment: Yes I tried in the advance options and run generic but it just write on the screen
Loading Linux 5.4.0-74-generic...and Loading initial ramdisk ...

Comment: Yes I tried the advance options and run with Linux generic. But it just write on the screen Loading Linux 5.4.0-74 ... and Loading initial ramdisk ... Just to be clear this one also appear forever.